# aggregating daily level data into a smaller format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have daily level data as mentioned below dataframe.

```
a = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b")
a = as.data.frame(a)
a$date = seq.Date(as.Date("2022-06-01"), as.Date("2022-06-10"), by = 1)
a$value = c(8,7,7,7,8,9,9,9,7,8)
```

The desired output should be

```
a = c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
a = as.data.frame(a)
a$startdate = c("2022-06-01","2022-06-02","2022-06-05","2022-06-06","2022-06-09","2022-06-10")
a$enddate = c("2022-06-01","2022-06-04","2022-06-05","2022-06-08","2022-06-09","2022-06-10")
a$value = c(8,7,8,9,7,8)
```

Thanks

I have tried one solution involving 2 for loops and then aggregation but it is very slow. It would be of great help if I get a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to filter to rows where there’s a change from the previous value?

```
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(value != lag(value, default = -Inf)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  a     date       value
  <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1 a     2022-06-01     8
2 a     2022-06-02     7
3 a     2022-06-05     8
4 b     2022-06-06     9
5 b     2022-06-09     7
6 b     2022-06-10     8
```

Comment: I want to make the data frame more compact in viewing. In the above logic if for all 5 days the value is same then I will not know the end date till the value is stretched, hence I need the end date column. If the value is same for all days then it should look like (a, 2022-06-01, 2022-06-05, 8).